# iOS 12: UITextField not deallocating

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios12

`UITextField` which is pre-filled with some text and with keyboard active is not deallocating when close controller. Here is an example:

```
class TextFieldViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        let textField = TestTextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        textField.text = "Text"//commment this line and deinit will be called

        view.addSubview(textField)
        textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }

    deinit {
        print("Deinit controller")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        (view.subviews.first as? UITextField)?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }}

}

class TestTextField: UITextField {

    deinit {
        print("never gets called")
    }

}
```

Code to present controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
            self?.present(TextFieldViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
                self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`deinit` of `TextFieldViewController` gets called but deinit of `TestTextField` is not. Text field remains in memory graph after closing of controller:

[image]

Interesting points:

- `textField.text = "Text"` comment this line and `deinit` of text
  field will be called. Even if you enter text from keyboard.
- keep`textField.text = "Text"` uncommented but comment `viewDidAppear`
  method (i.e. don't open keyboard) and `deinit` of text field will be
  called.
- Problem is there seems only on ios 12.1+

Comment: Looks like an apple bug (again, i've seen this in some ios11 versions). But if you are forcefully becoming firstresponder, you should balance that and call resignFirstResponder in viewWillDisappear

Comment: just checked and it doesn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... this does look like a bug.

Quick testing indicates it occurs if the `.text` property of the text field is assigned before it becomes the responder, but the problem does *not* happen if you do it afterwards.

So, if you're looking for a "workaround," you could do this...

Comment-out the line in `viewDidLoad()` as you indicated:

```
//textField.text = "Text"//commment this line and deinit will be called
```

and then add a line *after* `.becomeFirstResponder()`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    (view.subviews.first as? UITextField)?.becomeFirstResponder()
    (view.subviews.first as? UITextField)?.text = "Text"
}
```

You'll "see" the text being added, as the text field will be empty as the view slides up. So, it may or may not be suitable.

Comment: thanks, but the code from the question is just example. In real app it's not really possible - there are some text fields which are pre-filled and there is no call of `becomeFirstResponder`. The user should tap text field to edit the text.